# Can i open native video playback for both (Androidt / IOS) With React Native?

Tags: react-native, android-intent, android-videoview, audiovideoplayback, youtube-ios-player-helper

How can I open a video in native playback ?!
Like anime, streaming apps, etc...

It doesn't work

```
Linking.openURL('video:http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4');  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for Android
Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import {NativeModules, Button} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const SendIntentAndroid = NativeModules?.SendIntentAndroid || {};

  const onPress = () => {
    SendIntentAndroid?.openAppWithData(
       null,                                        // Package name
      'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4', // uri
      'video/*',                                    // mime/type
      {},                                           // extras
    );
  };
  return <Button onPress={onPress} title={'Open video playback'} />;
};

export default App;
```

If doesn't work TRY TO INSTALL

```
yarn add react-native-send-intent
```

```
npm install react-native-send-intent
```

Environment:

- React-native : "0.64.2" - CLI
- Android Device
- Windows 10